# jQuery replacing string

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I have the following html. I need a jquery function that
replaces just the string 'Price' with a different string. I tried `text()` and `html()`, but didn't work.

```
<div class="price_label" style="">
Price: <span class="from">$160.00</span> — <span class="to">$15,950.00</span>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
jQuery('div.price_label).text('newstring')
jQuery('div.price_label).first().text('newstring')
```

But didn't work. jQuery gets the selector ok. but
the whole div is replaced. Not just string 'Price'.
Please help!!

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: `.html()` works fine, consider this: `$('.price_label').html($('.price_label').html().replace('Price: ', 'Ciao! '))`

Comment: thank Dimitris. I searched stackoverflow and tried this, it works ok:

Comment: $(".price_label").text(function(index, text) { 
    return text.replace('Price', 'New Price'); 
});

Comment: _"But didn't work."_ That's hardly a detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const priceLabel = $('.price_label')[0]
priceLabel.innerHTML = priceLabel.innerHTML.replace("Price: ", "")
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="price_label" style="">
Price: <span class="from">$160.00</span> — <span class="to">$15,950.00</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This work fine:

```
$(".price_label").text(function(index, text) { 
    return text.replace('Price', 'New Price'); 
});
```